# Write failed login attemps to apache error_log

Tags: php, security, apache, error-handling

I would like to improve my PHP CMS security in that it writes failed login attempts to the Apache error log. My idea for this is that it would then work with fail2ban, banning any IPaddresses that are trying to drut force guess the password of the CMS admin login.

Also if I have a vhost file set up an additional error log in the vhost such as below can I work out in PHP which error log to write to?

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.co.uk-error.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options to achieve that:

The [`error_log()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function will by default write to your server's error_log (the error log of your apache vhost in your case).

The [`syslog()`](http://php.net/syslog) function will write to the system logger. You can use [`openlog()`](http://php.net/openlog) before calling `syslog()` to set the syslog facility (e.g. LOG_AUTH).

Comment: Is there a correct format/practice etc that I should follow when writing to the error logs?

Comment: Found a useful page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073164/write-to-error-log-with-local-time-information-and-a-line-break-at-the-end

Answer (score 0):

Code(PHP):

```
<?php
error_log('test');
```

Log entry:

```
[Sun Aug 14 18:44:11 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] test
```